# Importing JSON string to Firebase domain

Tags: json, firebase

I would pull data from an api and store the data in my Firebase domain.  Is this possible?

Reading up I can't find any docs on how to do this.  Even if it was to fetch from a database as well.  Am I overlooking something silly?

Comment: If the API is JavaScript based, you can just read the data in your web page (or server-side using something like node.js) and store it to Firebase using their JavaScript API. The Firebase JavaScript API for writing data is pretty well documented here: https://www.firebase.com/docs/writing-data.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase ops are completed using JSON data. Assuming your source API provides valid JSON, and that the keys don't contain any [restricted characters](https://www.firebase.com/docs/creating-references.html)--i.e. .$[]#/--then you may simply call the [set](https://www.firebase.com/docs/javascript/firebase/set.html) op as normal:

```
function fetchPayload(callback) {
  /* do some API magic to get your data, then invoke callback */
}

function storeInFirebase( payload ) {
   new Firebase(URL).set( payload );
}

fetchPayload(storeInFirebase);
```

You can also click the import button in forge (by going to your Firebase URL in a browser):

[image: import button in Forge]

Be sure to export a backup first if you have any existing data! :)